# Android Multimedia Tunneling Sync Header

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec, audiotrack

**Context**

I'm creating an Android application playing Media Source Extensions streams using [Multimedia Tunneling](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/multimedia-tunneling). I'm using the API call flow as provided by the documentation. Audio part is handled with an `AudioTrack`. `AudioSessionID` is shared between the video `MediaCodec` and `AudioTrack`. Android SDK version is 26.

[image: API call flow]

**Problem**

Video is being played correctly but no audio can be heard.

- I do not have any error reported by the API.
- Buffers are written in `OutputBuffer` using `AudioTrack.write`.
- Non tunneling playback audio works well.
- `audio_hal` does not produce any error in the logs.

**Question**

I've looked into the `ExoPlayer` implementation and I see the use of a sync header before writing the buffer to the `AudioTrack` in tunneling playback.

```
ByteBuffer avSyncHeader = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
avSyncHeader.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
avSyncHeader.putInt(0x55550001);
avSyncHeader.putInt(4, size);
avSyncHeader.putLong(8, presentationTimeUs * 1000);
avSyncHeader.position(0);
audioTrack.write(avSyncHeader, avSyncHeader.remaining(), WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
```

I have tried adding that header too but audio was still not heard.

Is this sync header necessary?

Is there any other non documented requirement for Multimedia Tunneling?

Answer (score 0):

Avsync header is for the level SDK, you can use another `AudioTrack.write`, to write the every buffer timestamp. It can auto generate the AV sync header.
Use another API, which can write timestamp.

Try:

```
int write(ByteBuffer audioData, int sizeInBytes, int writeMode, long timestamp)
```

> Writes the audio data to the audio sink for playback in streaming mode on a HW_AV_SYNC track

Comment: What is the recommended write mode in case of multimedia tunneling? Blocking or unblocking?

Comment: Also can work, Of course, I will suggest you to use no block mode, so it will not block your thread, but you need to query and retry to write data. If you use block mode, it will block your thread. Any method all can work, by your use

Comment: You need to notice that, for the pcm data, the tunnel mode may also can't support float mode. You can check your device's audio policy xml config.